# select date range which overlap a certain date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Lets say this my table like below.

```
ID | Startdate           | Enddate
-----------------------------------------------
1  | 2012-12-12 08:00:00 | 2012-12-15 18:30:00
-----------------------------------------------
2  | 2012-12-11 00:00:00 | 2012-12-16 00:00:00
-----------------------------------------------
3  | 2012-12-16 08:00:00 | 2012-12-17 18:30:00
-----------------------------------------------
4  | 2012-12-13 00:00:00 | 2012-12-14 11:30:00
-----------------------------------------------
```

the selected date range is Id 1, 2012-12-12 08:00:00  to 2012-12-15 18:30:00 . 
I wanna select any date which will across the date range.

The correct Id will be, 2 and 4 . 
Hope you guys understand, if any question please feel free to ask.
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? We'll help you with specific code but SO isn't a place to have your coding done for you.

Comment: JaredMcAteer, thank for your advise, i will show the code i have try next time, sorry this is my first post. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select d1.*
from
  dates d1 inner join dates d2
  on d2.id=1 and d1.Startdate<d2.Enddate and d1.Enddate>d2.Startdate
where d1.id<>1
```

Comment: Thank you, i did try, but it get id 2 ,3 ,4 . Anywhere, thank your try  !

Comment: @user1898109 with your sample data, i get 2 and 4 which are all dates that overlaps date range with id=1. Your accepted answer returns only 4....

Comment: Ops, sorry, cos my own data is different, i make mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM YourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT StartDate, EndDate
   FROM YourTable 
   WHERE Id = 1
) t2 ON t2.StartDate < t1.StartDate AND t2.EndDate > t1.EndDate
```